# How do I prevent opportunity stages going backwards direction ? salesforce

Tags: validation-rule

How do I prevent opportunity stages going backwards direction ? using validation rule salesforce

Answer (score 1):

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_useful_validation_formulas_oppty_mgmt.htm&type=5

There's a help document with lots of validation examples. Their example utilizes some sort of approval process which you may or may not have after a certain stage point.

[image]

Otherwise, I'd utilize the case function to get this functionality where you can assign a number value to each stage and then compare the current stage number to the prior number.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_a_h.htm&type=0

```
CASE(StageName,
"Stage1", 1,
"Stage2", 2,
"Stage3", 3,
"Stage4", 4, 0) > 
CASE(TEXT(PRIORVALUE(StageName)),
"Stage1", 1,
"Stage2", 2,
"Stage3", 3,
"Stage4", 4, 0)
```